# ORACLE import/export CLOB data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, storage, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import an excel file into an oracle table via sql developer. One of the oracle columns is of type CLOB, and during the verification step of the import wizard, i get the following message in the information column: "Data Types CLOB, not supported for import." The data fields i am attempting to import for the CLOB column is empty. Does anybody have any idea what might be wrong? Thanks.

If it is not possible, How can I import/export CLOB data in Oracle?

Comment: Does error raise when importing not empty CLOB?

Comment: First, an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx) is generally a binary file format so you would generally load it into a `BLOB` not a `CLOB`.  Are you certain that you want to load the data into a `CLOB` and that you understand exactly how that will affect the file?  Second, are you saying that the data is currently `NULL`?  Or is it set to `EMPTY_CLOB`?

Comment: I use CLOB data for a long text fields (as 'text' in mysql). I understand that BLOB is just for storing bytes (normally files) into the DB. Second, these fields are not shown in the generated SQL, as if they didn't exist. Kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a more recent copy of SQL Developer. We support importing into a CLOB field now from Excel.

[image]

And then when it's over, checking the data...

[image]